# VueJS returning value from Vuex not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to implement a messaging/alerting system through Vuex and from the various components on a click method - for example - pass an argument that tells vuex getter which message to display. Except that it is not returning the any data.

I know this may be overkill just for a simple flash messaging system, but it server a greater purpose once I get it working properly.

At the moment, I am passing the message key/name for matching in the state alertMessages array via the Alert component, but eventually this would be passed from the Login Component upon a method call.

Structure:

```
• App.vue
--> • Alert component
--> • Login component (login method)
--> • NavHeader component
    --> Logout Btn (logout method)
• Store.js
```

Here's what I have:
Store.js:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      alertMessages: [
         { key: "loginSuccess", alert: "logged in.", redirectPath: "dashboard" },
         { key: "loginError", alert: "try again.", redirectPath: "login" }
      ]
   },
   getters: {
      pickMessage: state => {
         return (something) => {
            state.alertMessages.forEach(msg => {
               if(msg.key == something){
                  // This return does not send any data through.
                  return msg.alert;
               }
            });
            // This return works. Alert gets Hey There.
            // return "Hey There";
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Alert.vue:
Template

```
<template>
   <div class="alert">
       {{message}}
   </div>
</template>
```

Scripts

```
export default {
   name: 'alert',
   data () {
      return {
         message: ''
      }
   },
   computed: {
      alertMessage: async function(){
         try {
            // Passing loginSuccess for key matching.
            this.message = this.$store.getters.pickMessage('loginSuccess');
         } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
         } finally {

         }
      }
   },
   created: function(){
      this.alertMessage;
   }
}
```

Seems the `if()` statement is doing something that prevents the return inside it to work. I know that the function argument from the Alert component is getting passed, because I can console log it. What am I missing here?

Thanks so much in advance,

Sergio

Comment: computed methods don't work with async, unless you have a plugin installed for that

Answer (score 1):

So, changing the getters to the code below worked...
Why exactly was making my initial code not work? Because the return was inside the forEach loop (multiple returns)?

Working code:

```
   getters: {
      pickMessage: state => {
         return (something) => {
          let val;
            state.alertMessages.forEach(msg => {
               if(msg.key == something){
                 val = msg.alert;
               }
            });
            // This return works. Alert gets Hey There.
            // return "Hey There";

            return val;
         }
      }
   }
```

**EDIT:**
An even cleaner solution is to replace the `forEach` loop with a `for...of` loop – Thanks Ujjwal Nepal!!!

Here is the code example:

```
getters: {
      pickMessage: state => {
         return (something) => {
            let arr = state.alertMessages
            for(let a of arr){
               if(a.key == something){
                  return a.alert;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This is exactly what utility libraries like lodash try to tackle.  `const result = _.find(state.alertMessages, { key: something });  return _.get(result, 'alert');`.  The second line is only necessary in case no alert messages were found - it handles the case where result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As per MDN the only way to terminate a forEach() loop is to throw exception. So there is no other way to terminate a forEach() loop that's the problem in your code above.

Comment: Aahhh... so to clean up the working code, I should be using a `for of` loop instead?

Comment: Yeah using a plain loop is the solution in your case.